# NSFetchedResultsController to only get first 10 items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController` (and the delegate methods) to display items from `CoreData` into a `UITableView`.

However, I only want the table to show the first few items (say 10).

To do this I have done this...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return MIN([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count], 10);
}
```

This will return 10 if there are more than 10 items. Or it will return the number of items if it is less than 10.

It works for the first 10 items downloaded. However, I then triggered a refresh of the downloaded data.

This added another 10 items to CoreData and then triggered the `FRC` delegate methods.

This caused an error saying...

```
There were 10 items before the update. You added 10 items. Now there are still 10 items but there should be 20.
```

This came from the `UITableView` `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` method.

I know that it is right as I am adding stuff to CoreData but I only still want it to show the first 10.

Is there an entirely different way of doing this? Or can I fix the delegate methods somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the begin and end updates methods, just reload the table view. This means you aren't telling the table about new rows (and how many there are).

Also, on the FRC, be sure to set the fetch limit on the fetch request so it doesn't fetch more than required.

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do was set the fetch limit on the fetch request and this has resolved the problem. The FRC doesn't get notified of additions outside the range it is interested in so all working :D

Comment: That is interesting. According to https://devforums.apple.com/message/279576#279576, the change tracking does not honour the fetch limit.

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's just the data I'm using. Will keep an eye on it.

Comment: OK, you were right. I had to remove the begin and end updates and just reload the tableview.